# EF - How to define a regular expression property using fluent EntityTypeConfiguration API?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Setting up properties using DataAnnotations is easy:

```
[RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\\.\\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\\.\\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

But how to do it using fluent API?

```
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        //email
        Property(p => p.Email).IsRequired();
        //setting up regex??
    }
}
```

Thanx!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `RegularExpressionAttribute` is not for EF, but that it is only used to generate validation in your view.

Comment: Well, the book I'm learning the EF by says that a good practice is not to mix fluent API with DataAnnotaions. I guess in this case I will have to make an exception. Although, it makes sense if you want to separate class declaration from configuration it should support not only the basic reqs. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: What I generally do is create 2 classes.. one for dealing with EF and another for presentation. You could use fluent style for the EF entity class and the extra annotations like `RegularExpression`, `Display`, etc in your presentation class.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that `RegularExpressionAttribute` is not for EF, but that it is only used to generate validation in your view. The fluent API is for configuring database properties.. so, `IsRequired()` will set the column to `NOT NULL`, etc.. I may be wrong, but I believe there's no support for regex constraints in SQL and you will find that's why there's nothing in the EF fluent configuration for it. It's for your views only...