# Regex validation in fluent Api (Entity Configuration)

Tags: c#, regex, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a .Net 7 server app and im using Entity Framework code first approach and I wonder, is there any way to enforce the regex pattern on the property directly on database using fluent api (entity configuration file)?

I've tried something like:

```cs
builder.HasIndex(e => e.Name)
    .HasDatabaseName("IX_Name_Regex")
    .HasFilter("[Name] ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$'")
    .IsUnique();
```

and:

```cs
builder.Property(it => it.Name)
    .HasMaxLength(256);
    .HasAnnotation("Name_Regex", @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$");
```

and some other mix but none of them are working.

I found an answer: [EF - How to define a regular expression property using fluent EntityTypeConfiguration API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285374/ef-how-to-define-a-regular-expression-property-using-fluent-entitytypeconfigur) but its 10 y/o, so I wonder, maybe it is a way to do this?